# Backbone arrow function and this

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I just switched my functions over to use arrow functions and now `this` only references the `Object` of my view.

**Original View**

```
var filterBar = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: () => {
    this.state = {
      teams: document.querySelectorAll('[data-team-default]')[0].innerHTML,
      comp: document.querySelectorAll('[data-comp-default]')[0].innerHTML,
      season: document.querySelectorAll('[data-season-default]')[0].innerHTML,
    };
  },
    el: '.filter-bar',
    templates: {
        home: require('../../../app/jade/games/index.jade')
    },
    events: {
        'click .filter-bar--filter-button': 'showFilter',
        'click .filter-bar--filter-list': 'changeFilter',
    },
  changeFilter: function (e) {
    const currentSelection = e.target.getAttribute('data-url');
    return false;
    },
  showFilter: function (e)  {
    console.info(this);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var t = $(e.currentTarget);
    this.closeFilters();
    t.siblings('ul').addClass('is-open');
    return false;
   },
  closeFilters: function (e) {
    var e = this.$el.find(".is-open");
    e.length && e.removeClass("is-open"),
     this.$el.hasClass("show-filters") && this.$el.removeClass("show-filters")
    }
});
```

Console output:
[image]

**Updated View**

```
var filterBar = Backbone.View.extend({
  changeFilter: (e) => {
      ......
    },
  showFilter: (e) => {
      console.info(this);
      ......
    },
  closeFilters: (e) => {
      ......
    }
});
```

Console output:  Object {}

Why is it that now, this only references the Object of the view and not the view itselfs. Furthermore, how can I get it back to reference the view whilst using arrow functions?

Actually the reason I moved to arrow functions was to access `this.state` set in my initialise.

I am using backbone version `1.3.3` with `Babel 2015`

Comment: Any mate, could I please just a little information on the down vote. Can I change the question in any place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm puzzled why you want to use arrow functions here at all. From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

[and](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods):

> **Arrow functions used as methods**
>
> As stated previously, arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions. [...]
>
> Arrow functions do not define ("bind") their own `this`.

The whole point of arrow functions is to have a short-form function without all the OO stuff (like `this`), they're really meant for cases where you don't care about `this` such as:

```
some_array.map(e => e * 2)
```

Given this:

```
// (a)
var filterBar = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: () => {
    // (b)
  }
});
```

the value of `this` at **(b)** is exactly the same as at **(a)**. `this` inside one of your view methods will never be the view instance without significant kludgery and gymnastics (and even then it might not even be possible to make `initialize` an arrow function).

**Summary**: Don't do that, that's not what arrow functions are for.

Comment: Puzzled you are and misinformed I was. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Comment: @JamieHutber Presumably you wrote that comment while wearing your Yoda hat you were :)