# Backbone collection add event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am writing a slightly modified version of the Backbone Todos app commonly found online, using books instead. My Backbone version is 1.3.3. Like the example, for now I am just trying to display a book title added by the user in an input list. My code (partial) is given below:

```
app.BookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.Book,
  // For temp use, to be replaced with URL
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('BookList')
});

app.bookList = new app.BookList();


app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',

  initialize: () => {
    this.input = this.$('#book-name');
    app.bookList.on('change', this.addOneBook, this);
    app.bookList.fetch();
  },

  events: {
    'keypress #book-name': 'createNewBookModel'
  },

  addOneBook: (book) => {
    console.log('BOOK: ', book);
    const b = new app.BookView({ model: book });
    this.$('#bookList').append(b.render().el());
  },

  createNewBookModel: (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        app.bookList.create({ title: this.input.val().trim() });
      this.input.val('');
    }
  }

});


app.appView = new app.AppView();
```

My problem is the `addOneBook` event is not firing, after the `createNewBookModel` event has fired and completed. My understanding (reading this - http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create), is that creating a model will trigger an `add` event on the collection. I tried using `bind` instead of `on`, but that didn't work. I also tried `this.listenTo` in place of `on`, but that threw an error, saying, `this.listenTo` is not defined. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone arrow function and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536327/backbone-arrow-function-and-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never made extensive use of ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but I think they may be causing you problems here. As I understand it, arrow functions do not bind the `this` object. While your functions are executing, your `this` will evaluate to undefined or maybe even the `window` parent object, but I think you want it to evaluate to the backbone object.

Try replacing:

```
initialize: () => {
  // ...
},
```

with:

```
initialize: function() {
  // ...
},
```

and similar for your other methods. I think that will clear up a lot of problems.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed was the problem!